# Importing Objects from different files in JavaScript Project

Tags: javascript, html, import, javascript-import

I am complete beginner in JavaScript and web-dev. Most of my programming experience comes from Python and so I am very comfortable with the way python files can be arranged in different folders as modules and can play sort of a plug and play role. So far I am unable to discover that flexibility in JS.

Here is my current project structure:

```
-root
 |-index.html
 |-app.js
 |-modules
   |-test.js
```

Here is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>My Project</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `app.js`:

```
let hello = Hello()
```

Finally my `modules/test.js`:

```
class Hello(){
  constructor(){
    console.log('Hello World');
  }
}
```

When I run it I get the error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Hello is not defined at app.js:1:1`

What do I do to achieve my desired results? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

modules/test.js:

```
export class Hello(){
  constructor(){
    console.log('Hello World');
  }
}
```

app.js:

```
import { Hello } from './modules'

let hello = new Hello()
```

Or, if you use the expor default, do not need the curly braces, as you do not need to secify what you are exporting. Like so:

modules/test.js:

```
export default class Hello(){
  constructor(){
    console.log('Hello World');
  }
}
```

app.js:

```
import Hello from './modules'

let hello = new Hello()
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your index.html, when you are working with modules, you should add the type of the script

```
<script type="module"></script>
```

In the modules, after you do some code and logic, you export your class with the export declaration at the end, like so:

```
export default Hello;
```

in your app.js, when you want to use some module, you import it like so:

```
import Hello from "./modules/test.js";
```

And then you would be able to use the imported data. You can use as many imports as you want.
Here is a working example with the minor tweaks on your code:
[CodeSanbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-framework-2hjmsq)

Answer (score 1):

So both the answers provided by [rustyBucketBay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72330888/12035668) and [Yavor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72331156/12035668) are correct but incomplete. The working solution is doing what each of the two suggested but together. Here is what eventually works:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>My Project</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`modules/test.js`:

```
export default class Hello{
  constructor(){
    console.log('Hello World');
  }
}
```

`app.js`:

```
import Hello from 'modules/test.js'
let hello = new Hello()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the function from test.js and import it in app.js